There is a vertical scrollbar, after the start and end of the X-axis change, the translateCoordination is not accurate
There is a vertical scrollbar, draw multiple curves, the X-axis remains unchanged, and the coordinates converted through translation coordination will be 1800. After the X-axis changes start and end, the coordinates converted again through translation coordination will be 600. How to maintain consistency in translation coordination
I tried to change the X-axis and executed translateCoordination, but found that it couldn't be achieved
`let containerBox = this.$refs.containerBox;
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        const locationClient = {
          clientX: containerBox.offsetWidth,
          clientY: containerBox.offsetHeight,
        };
        this.chart.translateCoordinate(locationClient, {
          x: this.axisX,
          y: this.axisY,
        });
      });`

